# Image size in a ScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, scrollview, swift3

I have a ScrollView with pictures. Since the transition to Xcode8 / Swift 3, the image no longer fits the size of ScrollView. Inside the image, keeps its original size when in Xcode 7/2 swift image which was perfectly adapted to scroll and matched perfectly. Below is the corresponding code:

```
import UIKit

class GoaLawahViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var PageControl: UIPageControl!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ScrollViewWidth:CGFloat = self.ScrollView.frame.width
        let scrollViewHeight:CGFloat = self.ScrollView.frame.height


        let imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,width: ScrollViewWidth, height: scrollViewHeight))
        imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "GoaLawah04.jpg")
        let imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: ScrollViewWidth, y: 0,width: ScrollViewWidth, height: scrollViewHeight))
        imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "GoaLawah07.jpg")
        let imgThree = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: ScrollViewWidth*2, y: 0,width: ScrollViewWidth, height: scrollViewHeight))
        imgThree.image = UIImage(named: "GoaLawah09.jpg")


        self.ScrollView.addSubview(imgOne)
        self.ScrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)
        self.ScrollView.addSubview(imgThree)


        self.ScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.ScrollView.frame.width * 3, height: 1.0)
        self.ScrollView.delegate = self
        self.PageControl.currentPage = 0


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
        // Test the offset and calculate the current page after scrolling ends
        let pageWidth:CGFloat = scrollView.frame.width
        let currentPage:CGFloat = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x-pageWidth/2)/pageWidth)+1
        // Change the indicator
        self.PageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add your imageViews on a containerView(just a new blank UIView),then add the containerView on your scrollView

Comment: Thank you for your back, actually this is a good solution but with this solution the paging does not work well when I scroll I see is the end of the previous image is the beginning of the next picture, although either scroll paging

Comment: What kind of result are you expecting?I'm not sure I get your point.

Comment: Hello, in fact according to my code I have the ScrollView with images. But in the simulation images are not adapted to the dimensions scroll. when I scroll I move across the width of the original image does not adapts. before xcode 2 7 swift they were adapting perfectly to scroll and spent the iamge image without problems

Comment: you mean the size of the image is smaller then the imageView.frame? If that's what you are saying, that has nothing to do with ScrollView,you may try to change the contentMode property of imageView.

Comment: No actually my image does not fit the size of my ScrollView, it retains its original size and my dns larger case.

I changed my code, now it works well. by against what I understand is I was also forced to remove constraints to position it displays correctly in my screen. if I do not remove constraints position the image to its normal size and will not fit.

Answer (score 0):

Attached is my new code and it works. against that by not understand is that I was forced to remove my position constraints for it to function properly

```
import UIKit
```

class PandangBaiViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var PageControl: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let ScrollViewWidth:CGFloat = self.ScrollView.frame.width
    let scrollViewHeight:CGFloat = self.ScrollView.frame.height


    let imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,width: ScrollViewWidth, height: scrollViewHeight))
    imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "1PadangBay.jpg")
    imgOne.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    self.ScrollView.addSubview(imgOne)


    let imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: ScrollViewWidth, y: 0,width: ScrollViewWidth, height: scrollViewHeight))
    imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "2PadangBay.jpg")
    imgTwo.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    self.ScrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)


    let imgThree = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: ScrollViewWidth*2, y: 0,width: ScrollViewWidth, height: scrollViewHeight))
    imgThree.image = UIImage(named: "PadangBaiinternet1.jpg")
    imgThree.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    self.ScrollView.addSubview(imgThree)


    let imgFour = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: ScrollViewWidth*3, y: 0,width: ScrollViewWidth, height: scrollViewHeight))
    imgFour.image = UIImage(named: "PadangBaiinternet2.jpg")
    imgFour.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    self.ScrollView.addSubview(imgFour)



    let imgFive = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: ScrollViewWidth*4, y: 0,width: ScrollViewWidth, height: scrollViewHeight))
   imgFive.image = UIImage(named: "PadangBaiinternet3.jpg")
    imgFive.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    self.ScrollView.addSubview(imgFive)



    self.ScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: ScrollViewWidth * 5, height: scrollViewHeight)
    self.ScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    self.PageControl.currentPage = 0


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
    // Test the offset and calculate the current page after scrolling ends
    let pageWidth:CGFloat = scrollView.frame.width
    let currentPage:CGFloat = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x-pageWidth/2)/pageWidth)+1
    // Change the indicator
    self.PageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage);

}
```

}